# Анимированное переключение маршрутов с загрузкой данных, Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Использую Vue, Vuex, Vue-router. Есть список из элементов router-link. По клику должен переключатся с анимацией компонент в области router-view и меняться url адрес маршрута. Те старый компонент должен полностью исчезнуть, затем идет запрос на сервер за данными для нового компонента, а потом плавно появляется новый компонент. Но так не происходит. После клика по router-link данные нового маршрута сразу быстро загружаются и плавно исчезает уже новый компонент, затем он же плавно появляется.

Что я делаю не так, что у меня исчезает уже новый компонент? Запрос за данными делаю в хуках beforeRouteEnter и beforeRouteUpdate.

LessonsList.vue

```
<template>
<section>
<ul>
         <router-link v-for="(lesson,index) in lessons"
                      v-bind:key="index"
                      :to="{
                         name: 'lesson',
                         params: {
                             id: index+1
                         }
                      }"
                      tag="li">
                     <h2>№{{index+1}}</h2>
         </router-link>
</ul>
<transition name="slide" mode="out-in" appear>
        <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
</transition>
</section>
```

Lesson.vue

```
import {store} from '../../vuex/store'

beforeRouteEnter(to,from,next) {
       let sendData = {};
       sendData.lessonNumber = Number(to.params.id);
       sendData.userId = store.getters['login/userId'];
       store.dispatch('lesson/changeCurrentLesson', sendData).then(()=> next());
       //пробрасываю action во vuex, где идет запрос на сервер за данными
   },
   beforeRouteUpdate(to,from,next){
       let sendData = {};
       sendData.lessonNumber = Number(to.params.id);
       sendData.userId = store.getters['login/userId'];
       store.dispatch('lesson/changeCurrentLesson', sendData).then(()=> next());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации Vue Router - Выборка данных](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation) :

> Иногда вам нужно получить данные с сервера, когда маршрут активирован.
> Например, перед рендерингом профиля пользователя вам необходимо
> получить данные пользователя с сервера. Мы можем достичь этого двумя
> разными способами:
>
> **Выборка после навигации** : сначала выполните навигацию и выберите
> данные в хуке жизненного цикла входящего компонента.
>
> **Выборка перед навигацией** : выберите данные перед навигацией по
> маршруту, выполните навигацию после получения данных.
>
> Технически оба варианта являются допустимыми - в конечном итоге это
> зависит от того, к какому вы стремитесь.

Чтобы второй вариант работал, как следует нужно иметь ввиду как работают хуки `beforeRouteEnter` и `beforeRouteUpdate` [Здесь](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4n%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) об этом подробнее можно почитать.

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    // вызывается до подтверждения пути, соответствующего этому компоненту.
    // НЕ ИМЕЕТ доступа к контексту экземпляра компонента `this`,
    // так как к моменту вызова экземпляр ещё не создан!
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // вызывается когда маршрут, что рендерит этот компонент изменился,
    // но этот компонент будет повторно использован в новом маршруте.
    // Например, для маршрута с динамическими параметрами `/foo/:id`, когда мы
    // перемещаемся между `/foo/1` и `/foo/2`, экземпляр того же компонента `Foo`
    // будет использован повторно, и этот хук будет вызван когда это случится.
    // Также имеется доступ в `this` к экземпляру компонента.
  },
```

И рабочий пример (Vue, Vuex, Vue Router):

```js
const UsersList = Vue.component('UsersList', {
  template: `
    <transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
      <router-view :key="$route.params.id"></router-view>
    </transition>`
})
const User = Vue.component('User', {
  template: `
    <section v-if="user">
      <h1>{{ user.name }}</h1>
      <h3>{{ user.email }}</h3>
      <p>{{ user.address.city }}/{{ user.address.street }}</p>
    </section>
  `,
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.getters.getCurrentUser
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.$store.dispatch('getUserFromApi', to.params.id)
    })
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    this.$store.commit('setUsers', null)
    this.$store.dispatch('getUserFromApi', to.params.id)
    next()
  }
})
const E404 = Vue.component('E404', {
  template: `
  <section>
    <h4>Error component</h4>
  </section>
  `
})

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    redirect: {
      name: 'userslist'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'userslist',
    path: '/userslist',
    component: UsersList,
    children: [{
      name: 'user',
      path: 'user:id',
      component: User
    }]
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    component: E404
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: () => {
    return {
      users: null,
      currentUser: null
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getCurrentUser: (state, getters) => {
      return state.currentUser
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setUsers(state, user) {
      state.currentUser = user
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async getUserFromApi({
      commit
    }, id) {
      await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((user) => {
          commit('setUsers', user)
        })
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  data: {
    users: []
  },
  async created() {
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.users = json
      })
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

hr {
  background: #eee;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
}

.left {
  max-width: 40%;
}

.right {
  max-width: 60%;
}

.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active до версии 2.1.8 */

{
  transform: translateY(40px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.5.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.8.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  Текущий URL - <b>{{ $route.path }}</b>
  <hr>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="left">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="index">
          <router-link :to="{
            name: 'user',
            params: {
              id: user.id
            }
          }" tag="a">{{ user.name }}</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```